# How does the JVM print something to the screen?

Tags: java, jvm, system.out

So I've been studying Java-bytecode and it's been fun so far, seeing how the JVM works. But there's something confusing me.

For example, if the JVM wants to do any sort of math, it uses registers to push/pop off the internal stack (oversimplifying it, I know).

But let's say the JVM wants to compute the bytecode version of this line:  `System.out.println("Hello");`

In the mnemonic version of the bytecode, I can see it searches for the System class in the java.lang package and invokes that method but what does that actually mean for the JVM?

Once the JVM reads the instruction and knows it has to print something, does it spawn a console window? Or can the JVM only do this type of instruction FROM the console? (So like for this, you would NEED to use the `java` tool)

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have experience with writing non-trivial java programs.

Comment: Basically all OS interaction (all IO system calls for example) aren't available as JVM bytecodes. Instead they are hidden within natively implemented methods in the standard class library (i.e. methods that have non-Java implementations).

Comment: The statement `System.out.println("Hello");` means “read the field `System.out` and invoke the `println` method of the referenced `PrintStream` instance”. In most environments, the `PrintStream` implementation is ordinary Java code, delegating to other Java code. If you are “studying Java-bytecode” and stopped at the very first method invocation, you didn’t get very far. I hope, you are aware that there are multiple classes having multiple methods. The typical underlying actions involve converting the string to a byte array using a charset encoding and calling `write` on a `FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any text written to `System.out` is sent to the *standard output* stream of the Operating System Process running the JVM.

The Operating System then decides what that means, which usually means printing the text to the console, if there is one.

It may also mean to write the text to a file, if *standard output* is redirected to a file, e.g. using the `>` syntax in a shell. Or it could mean sending the text to another process if *standard output* is piped, e.g. using the `|` syntax in a shell.

The JVM never "knows" it has to print something. The method is named `print` as a convenience to programmers for historical reasons, but is really no different from `write`.